# How do I redo an iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would I do here to get my code to go back an iteration?

```
list_ = [3,'yes',True]
for x in range(len(list_)):
    print('What is the next item in the list?')
    answer = input()
    if answer = list_[x]:
        print('Good job!')
    else:
        print('Nope! Try again.')
```

At that very last portion of the code (the 'else' statement) how would I get it to go over the same iteration of the for loop again so that the user can try again?

Comment: You can't really do that to the `for` loop, but you can add another `while` loop inside it that keeps prompting until the outer loop can continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't repeat an iteration, per se. What you can do is loop over the prompt until you get the right answer.

```
for x in range(len(list_)):
    while True:
        print('What is the next item in the list?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == list_[x]:
            print('Good job!')
            break
        else:
            print('Nope! Try again.')
```

By the way, looping over the indices of the list isn't necessary, at least not in this sample code. It'd be more idiomatic to loop over the list items directly.

```
for x in list_:
    while True:
        print('What is the next item in the list?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == x:
            print('Good job!')
            break
        else:
            print('Nope! Try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a while loop you could define your loop in a method with a flag that will call itself again if the answer is incorrect. The while loop is probably a nicer way to handle this though.

```
    def askQuestions():
        list_ = [3,'yes',True]
        allcorrect = True
        for x in range(len(list_)):
            print('What is the next item in the list?')
            answer = input()
            if answer == list_[x]:
                print('Good job!')
            else:
                print('Nope! Try again.')
                allcorrect = False
                break
        if not allcorrect:
            askQuestions()

askQuestions()
```